# bootstrap navbar displays vertically instead of horizontally

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

On my page `navbar` appears vertically instead of horizontally.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1,shrink-to-fit=no">
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>
            Home | Bootstrap
        </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-faded">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">My bootstrap application</a>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="about.html">About</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <form class="form-inline pull-xs-right">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search" />
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>
        </nav>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <h1>hello world!</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    Bootstrap 4
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

[Sample](https://jsfiddle.net/tpvqzmy4/)

Why is that? According to the docs it should horizontal by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `navbar-toggleable-md` class in `nav` element to make it looks horizontally in `md` view :

[See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tpvqzmy4/9/)

**[Docs](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar) :**

The original answer applied to Bootstrap 4 alpha. For **Bootstrap 4.0+**, the `navbar-toggleable-*` classes have changed to `navbar-expand-*`. Use one of the `navbar-expand-*` classes to keep the Navbar horizontal.

Comment: I am seeing the same thing with almost identical code and this doesn't fix the problem

Comment: Yeah, i'm confused here.  By default, the VS2017/Angular project gives a vertical menu bar, the "Docs" link you sent gives no help on how to change it to become horizontal, and even your demo shows a vertically-stacked menu bar.   Has something changed in bootstrap ?

Comment: Please check this link : https://jsfiddle.net/tr4gs9zu/1/ 
I've changed `navbar-toggleable-md` to `navbar-toggleable-sm` so the menu become horizontal above `sm` window width size. You can try to resize the output window to see the change.